# Flutter: Why is this variable not updating properly?

Tags: sql, sql-server, flutter, dart

I'm using the package [`sql_conn`](https://pub.dev/packages/sql_conn) and I want to create a "wrapper" that constantly checks the `SqlConn.isConnected` value to determine if the user can continue using the app. If this value is false, the user should be considered "logged out" and therefore the app should show the login screen.

When I run the app, the current state of `SqlConn.isConnected` is false. I then hit the Connect button and it connects just fine. I can hit the Read button and it successfully returns data.

However, the problem is when I hot restart. When I do this, the value of `SqlConn.isConnected` reads false, yet if I hit the Read button I can still query the database! What is going on?

```
import 'package:ats/providers/globals_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sql_conn/sql_conn.dart';

class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  const Login({super.key});

  @override
  State<Login> createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  final globals = GlobalsProvider();

  Future<void> connect(BuildContext ctx) async {
    debugPrint("Connecting...");
    try {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return const AlertDialog(
            title: Text("LOADING"),
            content: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        },
      );
      await SqlConn.connect(
          ip: "ipAddress",
          port: "1433",
          databaseName: "DB",
          username: "sa",
          password: "password");
      debugPrint("Connected!");
      updateConnectionStatus();
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
      updateConnectionStatus();
    } finally {
      Navigator.pop(context);
    }
  }

  Future<void> read(String query) async {
    var res = await SqlConn.readData(query);
    debugPrint(res.toString());
  }

  Future<void> write(String query) async {
    var res = await SqlConn.writeData(query);
    debugPrint(res.toString());
  }

  Future<void> disconnect() async {
    SqlConn.disconnect();
    updateConnectionStatus();
  }

  void updateConnectionStatus() {
    globals.connected = SqlConn.isConnected;
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Login'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (kDebugMode) {
                      print('${globals.debugATS} globals.connected: ${globals.connected.toString()}');
                      print('${globals.debugATS} SqlConn.isConnected: ${SqlConn.isConnected.toString()}');
                    }
                  },
                  child: const Text('Check connection status')
              ),
              Text('globals.connected: ${globals.connected.toString()}'),
              Text('SqlConn.isConnected: ${SqlConn.isConnected.toString()}'),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () => connect(context),
                  child: const Text("Connect")),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () => read("SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE"),
                  child: const Text("Read")),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () => disconnect(),
                  child: const Text("Disconnect"))
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Try using `SELECT GETDATE() AS NOW;` for your read query to see if the result is actually updating (i.e.: Flutter might be caching stale results). The reason I suggest this is because if you look at [the source of `SqlConnPlugin`](https://github.com/VaishnavDatir/sql_conn/blob/master/android/src/main/kotlin/plugin/sqlconn/sql_conn/SqlConnPlugin.kt) you'll notice that the `readDataFromDB` method doesn't alter the `result: Result` object in any way (to indicate either success or failure) when the connection hasn't been initialized.

Comment: I would recommend finding a different library to do this. `sql_conn` is just wrapping the ancient `net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver` driver, which hasn't seen a software update and release in very nearly ten years. It won't support any of the protocol features added to currently supported versions of SQL Server.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning oh no!! This was the only sql package I could find! :(

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I used `SELECT GETDATE()` and it's definitely giving me the current date and time, i.e. not caching stale results.